# Magento - Displaying Configurable Product Options under a Grouped Product

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am trying to create a grouped product by grouping some configurable products. I know it is possible. The grouped products attributes should be set to Not Required. This is found on Inchoo's website.

What I am trying to achieve here is that, I want to show the options of the configurable under the grouped products grid.

For example, I have a product range called Melina Table. This will be a grouped product to show 5 sizes of the product and customer can pick one. But under the 5 sizes, there will be two colour options each.

I am struggling to find a straight forward solution for this.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps showing some more details of your products/attributes structure would be helpful.

Comment: Inchoo's example about Chef's knives is an inappropriate use of grouped products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm confused as to why you are using a grouped product for this.  A grouped product should be a set of different products, such as a computer, monitor, keyboard, and mouse.

When you have something that has sizes and colors, but is essentially the same product, you really only need to make 1 configurable product.

You can create a configurable product with any number of attributes that it's based off of.  If you make a configurable product based on size and color, then create all your options (simple products), Magento will be smart enough to make it work.  You'll see two dropdown menus to select on the product view page, and after you select the first, the second will update accordingly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the timely answer. I have been using Magento for a year and a half now. I do understand how the product types work. I have one customer who is wanting to mix both Grouped and Configurable products on their website. That's why I am trying to display the custom options of the simple product on the grouped product page. I also think Magento lacks in this area. How would you list a simple product with custom options (or grouped product) under a grouped product. You can do so if the options are not required. What if the custom option is required?

Comment: I agree with this answer... your use of "Grouped Products" seems to be completely against its purpose... a Grouped Product should not be used as a way to show related products together so that the user simply chooses one of them.  Use a single configurable product.

Comment: Sid Vel - Unfortunately, Magento doesn't allow you to do what you need to do.  You can't have configurable products as a part of a grouped product, and you can't have any simple products with required custom options be a part of a grouped product either.  That's just the way they chose to set it up.  I'm sure there's a way to build a module to change the functionality on this, but that would definitely require some good time invested in figuring it all out.

Comment: Prattski is correct.  You cannot "group configurables." Our site allows you to configure art and a shirt.  We hoped to do "GCs" (what we ended up calling them) but had to code around it.

Comment: Spaldy - Is it possible that you could help me with the GCs?